# Amazon SES 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to use Amazon SES to send email to my corporate account. I have copied by aws access keys to ~/.aws/credentials file. Seems i am consistently getting the error:

> Error message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/

amz-sdk-invocation-id:638ed10a-22cd-12f5-c9a5-25a672a6c38d
amz-sdk-retry:3/136/485
host:email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-sdk-java/1.11.172 Mac_OS_X/10.11.5 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.60-b23/1.8.0_60
x-amz-date:20170808T040309Z

amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-retry;host;user-agent;x-amz-date
1c21e3af09924eec311e370c8e6710c0bc3fa2027fe213db11f02b22d79b6c91'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170808T040309Z
20170808/us-east-1/ses/aws4_request
82a2179c0dda36b0a4f80c111a8119cc8a65d768a0ff65de4c9b7ccf69a6b68a' (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 7dbfbcaa-7bee-11e7-a445-27be327c79a0)
com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/

amz-sdk-invocation-id:638ed10a-22cd-12f5-c9a5-25a672a6c38d
amz-sdk-retry:3/136/485
host:email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-sdk-java/1.11.172 Mac_OS_X/10.11.5 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.60-b23/1.8.0_60
x-amz-date:20170808T040309Z

amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-retry;host;user-agent;x-amz-date
1c21e3af09924eec311e370c8e6710c0bc3fa2027fe213db11f02b22d79b6c91'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170808T040309Z
20170808/us-east-1/ses/aws4_request
82a2179c0dda36b0a4f80c111a8119cc8a65d768a0ff65de4c9b7ccf69a6b68a' (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 7dbfbcaa-7bee-11e7-a445-27be327c79a0)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1587)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257)

Code base:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.RawMessage;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendRawEmailRequest;

public class SESClient {


  private static String EMAIL_FROM      = "@@@@@@@@@@";    
  private static String EMAIL_REPLY_TO  = "@@@@@@@@@@";  
  private static String EMAIL_RECIPIENT = "@@@@@@@@@@"; 

                                                                              // Remember to use two slashes in place of each slash.


  private static Regions AWS_REGION = Regions.US_EAST_1;           




  private static String EMAIL_SUBJECT   = "Amazon SES email test";
  private static String EMAIL_BODY_TEXT = "This MIME email was sent through Amazon SES using SendRawEmail.";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT, "UTF-8");

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EMAIL_FROM));
        message.setReplyTo(new Address[]{new InternetAddress(EMAIL_REPLY_TO)});
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(EMAIL_RECIPIENT));

        // Cover wrap
        MimeBodyPart wrap = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Alternative TEXT/HTML content
        MimeMultipart cover = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        MimeBodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();
        cover.addBodyPart(html);

        wrap.setContent(cover);

        MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart("related");
        message.setContent(content);
        content.addBodyPart(wrap);

        String[] attachmentsFiles = new String[]{
            //EMAIL_ATTACHMENTS
        };


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String attachmentFileName : attachmentsFiles) {
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            sb.append("<img src=\"cid:");
            sb.append(id);
            sb.append("\" alt=\"ATTACHMENT\"/>\n");

            MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();

            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(attachmentFileName);
            attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            attachment.setHeader("Content-ID", "<" + id + ">");
            attachment.setFileName(fds.getName());

            content.addBodyPart(attachment);
        }

        html.setContent("<html><body><h1>HTML</h1>\n" + EMAIL_BODY_TEXT + "</body></html>", "text/html");

        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES by using the AWS SDK for Java...");

            /*
             * The ProfileCredentialsProvider will return your [default]
             * credential profile by reading from the credentials file 
             * located at
             * (~/.aws/credentials).
             *
             * TransferManager manages a pool of threads, so we create a
             * single instance and share it throughout our application.
             */
            AWSCredentials credentials = null;
            try {
                credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new AmazonClientException(
                        "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                        "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                        "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                        e);
            }


            AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);
            Region REGION = Region.getRegion(AWS_REGION);
            client.setRegion(REGION);

            // Print the raw email content on the console
            PrintStream out = System.out;
            message.writeTo(out);

            // Send the email.
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            message.writeTo(outputStream);
            RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));

            SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
            client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
            System.out.println("Email sent!");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
          System.out.println("Email Failed");
            System.err.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code used for the error:

Comment: I found the answer as something wrong with the AWS keys. However, i dont think that is the issue.

Comment: So what do you mean by that? did you find your answer or didn't you?

Comment: For tips on how to ask a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Nope.. i am getting the error: (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 7dbfbcaa-7bee-11e7-a445-27be327c79a0)

Comment: A mismatched key and secret is the most likely explanation, here.  Specifically, your key is probably right but the secret is wrong, due to a copying error.  If the key were not a valid key, it would be rejected outright, with a different error about the key "not found in our records."

Comment: Your server Date/Time should be up to date.